# How to create a server control on another ASPX file

Tags: c#, asp.net, server.transfer

I am developing a C#/SQL ASP.NET web application in VS 2008.  Currently, I am transferring control from one ASPX file to another:

```
    if (uploadFile.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        inputfile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
        Context.Items["Message"] = inputfile; //Page1
        Server.Transfer("DataMatch.aspx"); //Page1
    }
```

However, it fails on this Server.Transfer line after inserting

```
runat="server"
```

in the DataMatch.aspx file to the Table element like so:

```
<table width="50%" id="tMain" runat="server">
```

But after making this a server control, I rebuilt it and now when I run this app it gives me exception:

```
Error executing child request for DataMatch.aspx
```

But I need this table to be a server control so I can make it invisible programmatically if a certain condition occurs.  How else can I programmatically make this table invisible?

Comment: You get this error if you do the Server.Transfer. But navigating DataMatch.aspx works fine?

Comment: Please avoid using `Server.Transfer`, using it is rarely a sign of good design...

Comment: Thanks guys.  I am mistaken.  This is not the cause of this exception.  I'm getting this exception regardless.  
Matti, what do you recommend I use instead of Server.Transfer?

Comment: if you're just trying to redirect the user to another page use Response.Redirect

Answer (score 0):

remove the "runat" tag from the table, and instead wrap it in an `<asp:Panel>` tag. Apply the visibility attribute to the panel.