# Server.transfer causing HttpException

Tags: c#, asp.net, server.transfer

I am developing a C#/SQL ASP.NET web application in VS 2008.  Currently I am using the Server.Transfer method to transfer control from one ASPX.CS file to another ASPX file.  The first time through, this works.  But after control is transferred to this new file it encounters a condition:

```
if (restart == false)
            {
```

where "restart" is a boolean variable.  After this statement it immediately transfers control back to the same ASPX.CS file and tries to reexecute the Server.Transfer method.  This time it gives me the following exception and stack trace.  Do you know what is causing this?  I tried to read this but it didn't make much sense to me.

System.Web.HttpException was unhandled by user code
  Message="Error executing child request for DataMatch.aspx."
  Source="System.Web"
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  StackTrace:
       at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(String path, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)
       at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Transfer(String path, Boolean preserveForm)
       at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Transfer(String path)
       at AddFileToSQL._Default.btnAppend_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\Default.aspx.cs:line 109
       at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputButton.OnServerClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException: System.Web.HttpCompileException
       Message="c:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx(14): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRowCollection.Add(System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow)' has some invalid arguments"
       Source="System.Web"
       ErrorCode=-2147467259
       SourceCode="#pragma checksum \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\" \"{406ea660-64cf-4c82-b6f0-42d48172a799}\" \"76750ABD913CF678D216C1E9CFB62BDF\"\r\n//------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r\n// \r\n//     This code was generated by a tool.\r\n//     Runtime Version:2.0.50727.3603\r\n//\r\n//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if\r\n//     the code is regenerated.\r\n// \r\n//------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r\n\r\nnamespace ASP {\r\n    \r\n    #line 285 \"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\web.config\"\r\n    using System.Web.Profile;\r\n    \r\n    #line default\r\n    #line hidden\r\n    \r\n    #line 280 \"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\web.config\"\r\n    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;\r\n    \r\n    #line default\r\n    #line hidden\r\n    \r\n    #line 282 \"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\web.config\"\r\n    using System.Web.Caching;\r\n    \r\n    #line default\r\n    #line hidden\r\n    \r\n    #line 278 \"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\web.config\"\r\n    using System.Configuration;\r\n    \r\n    #line default\r\n    #line hidden\r\n    \r\n    #line 277 \"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\web.config\"\r\n    using System.Collections.Specialized;\r\n    \r\n    #line default\r\n    #line hidden\r\n    \r\n    #line 19 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n    using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;\r\n    \r\n    #line default\r\n    #line hidden\r\n    \r\n    #line 289 \"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\web.config\"\r\n    using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;\r\n    \r\n    #line default\r\n    #line hidden\r\n    \r\n    #line 19 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;\r\n    \r\n    #line default\r\n    #line hidden\r\n    \r\n    #line 19 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n    using System.Web.UI;\r\n    \r\n    #line default\r\n    #line hidden\r\n    \r\n    #line 276 \"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\web.config\"\r\n    using System.Collections;\r\n    \r\n    #line default\r\n    #line hidden\r\n    \r\n    #line 275 \"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\web.config\"\r\n    using System;\r\n    \r\n    #line default\r\n    #line hidden\r\n    \r\n    #line 284 \"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\web.config\"\r\n    using System.Web.Security;\r\n    \r\n    #line default\r\n    #line hidden\r\n    \r\n    #line 281 \"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\web.config\"\r\n    using System.Web;\r\n    \r\n    #line default\r\n    #line hidden\r\n    \r\n    #line 283 \"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\web.config\"\r\n    using System.Web.SessionState;\r\n    \r\n    #line default\r\n    #line hidden\r\n    \r\n    #line 279 \"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\web.config\"\r\n    using System.Text;\r\n    \r\n    #line default\r\n    #line hidden\r\n    \r\n    \r\n    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGlobalScopeAttribute()]\r\n    public class datamatch_aspx : global::AddFileToSQL.DataMatch, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState, System.Web.IHttpHandler {\r\n        \r\n        private static bool @__initialized;\r\n        \r\n        private static object @__fileDependencies;\r\n        \r\n        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]\r\n        public datamatch_aspx() {\r\n            string[] dependencies;\r\n            ((global::AddFileToSQL.DataMatch)(this)).AppRelativeVirtualPath = \"~/DataMatch.aspx\";\r\n            if ((global::ASP.datamatch_aspx.@__initialized == false)) {\r\n                dependencies = new string[1];\r\n                dependencies[0] = \"~/DataMatch.aspx\";\r\n                global::ASP.datamatch_aspx.@__fileDependencies = this.GetWrappedFileDependencies(dependencies);\r\n                global::ASP.datamatch_aspx.@__initialized = true;\r\n            }\r\n            this.Server.ScriptTimeout = 30000000;\r\n        }\r\n        \r\n        protected System.Web.Profile.DefaultProfile Profile {\r\n            get {\r\n                return ((System.Web.Profile.DefaultProfile)(this.Context.Profile));\r\n            }\r\n        }\r\n        \r\n        protected ASP.global_asax ApplicationInstance {\r\n            get {\r\n                return ((ASP.global_asax)(this.Context.ApplicationInstance));\r\n            }\r\n        }\r\n        \r\n        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]\r\n        private global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTitle @__BuildControl__control3() {\r\n            global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTitle @__ctrl;\r\n            \r\n            #line 6 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl = new global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTitle();\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            return @__ctrl;\r\n        }\r\n        \r\n        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]\r\n        private global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlHead @__BuildControl__control2() {\r\n            global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlHead @__ctrl;\r\n            \r\n            #line 5 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl = new global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlHead(\"head\");\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTitle @__ctrl1;\r\n            \r\n            #line 5 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl1 = this.@__BuildControl__control3();\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            System.Web.UI.IParserAccessor @__parser = ((System.Web.UI.IParserAccessor)(@__ctrl));\r\n            \r\n            #line 5 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__parser.AddParsedSubObject(@__ctrl1);\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            \r\n            #line 5 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__parser.AddParsedSubObject(new System.Web.UI.LiteralControl(\"\r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n\"));\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            return @__ctrl;\r\n        }\r\n        \r\n        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]\r\n        private global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow @__BuildControl__control5() {\r\n            global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow @__ctrl;\r\n            \r\n            #line 15 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl = new global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow();\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            return @__ctrl;\r\n        }\r\n        \r\n        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]\r\n        private global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder @__BuildControlphTextBoxes() {\r\n            global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder @__ctrl;\r\n            \r\n            #line 19 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl = new global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder();\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            this.phTextBoxes = @__ctrl;\r\n            \r\n            #line 19 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl.ID = \"phTextBoxes\";\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            return @__ctrl;\r\n        }\r\n        \r\n        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]\r\n        private global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell @__BuildControl__control8() {\r\n            global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell @__ctrl;\r\n            \r\n            #line 18 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl = new global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell(\"td\");\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            \r\n            #line 18 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl.Align = \"center\";\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            \r\n            #line 18 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl.VAlign = \"top\";\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            System.Web.UI.IParserAccessor @__parser = ((System.Web.UI.IParserAccessor)(@__ctrl));\r\n            \r\n            #line 18 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__parser.AddParsedSubObject(new System.Web.UI.LiteralControl(\"\r\n                \"));\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder @__ctrl1;\r\n            \r\n            #line 18 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl1 = this.@__BuildControlphTextBoxes();\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            \r\n            #line 18 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__parser.AddParsedSubObject(@__ctrl1);\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            \r\n            #line 18 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__parser.AddParsedSubObject(new System.Web.UI.LiteralControl(\"\r\n            \"));\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            return @__ctrl;\r\n        }\r\n        \r\n        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]\r\n        private global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label @__BuildControlInstructions() {\r\n            global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label @__ctrl;\r\n            \r\n            #line 22 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl = new global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label();\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            this.Instructions = @__ctrl;\r\n            @__ctrl.ApplyStyleSheetSkin(this);\r\n            \r\n            #line 22 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl.ID = \"Instructions\";\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            \r\n            #line 22 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl.Font.Italic = true;\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            \r\n            #line 22 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl.Text = \"Now select from the dropdownlists which table columns from my database you want t\" +\r\n                \"o map these fields to\";\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            return @__ctrl;\r\n        }\r\n        \r\n        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]\r\n        private global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell @__BuildControl__control9() {\r\n            global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell @__ctrl;\r\n            \r\n            #line 21 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl = new global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell(\"td\");\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            System.Web.UI.IParserAccessor @__parser = ((System.Web.UI.IParserAccessor)(@__ctrl));\r\n            \r\n            #line 21 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__parser.AddParsedSubObject(new System.Web.UI.LiteralControl(\"\r\n                \"));\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label @__ctrl1;\r\n            \r\n            #line 21 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl1 = this.@__BuildControlInstructions();\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            \r\n            #line 21 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__parser.AddParsedSubObject(@__ctrl1);\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            \r\n            #line 21 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__parser.AddParsedSubObject(new System.Web.UI.LiteralControl(\"\r\n            \"));\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            return @__ctrl;\r\n        }\r\n        \r\n        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]\r\n        private global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button @__BuildControlbtnSubmit() {\r\n            global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button @__ctrl;\r\n            \r\n            #line 26 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl = new global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button();\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            this.btnSubmit = @__ctrl;\r\n            @__ctrl.ApplyStyleSheetSkin(this);\r\n            \r\n            #line 26 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl.ID = \"btnSubmit\";\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            \r\n            #line 26 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl.Text = \"Submit\";\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            \r\n            #line 26 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl.Width = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit(150, System.Web.UI.WebControls.UnitType.Pixel);\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            \r\n            #line 26 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            ((System.Web.UI.IAttributeAccessor)(@__ctrl)).SetAttribute(\"style\", \"top:auto; left:auto\");\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            \r\n            #line 26 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            ((System.Web.UI.IAttributeAccessor)(@__ctrl)).SetAttribute(\"top\", \"100px\");\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            \r\n            #line 26 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl.Click -= new System.EventHandler(this.btnSubmit_Click);\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            \r\n            #line 26 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnSubmit_Click);\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            return @__ctrl;\r\n        }\r\n        \r\n        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]\r\n        private global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell @__BuildControl__control10() {\r\n            global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell @__ctrl;\r\n            \r\n            #line 25 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl = new global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell(\"td\");\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            \r\n            #line 25 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl.Align = \"center\";\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            System.Web.UI.IParserAccessor @__parser = ((System.Web.UI.IParserAccessor)(@__ctrl));\r\n            \r\n            #line 25 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__parser.AddParsedSubObject(new System.Web.UI.LiteralControl(\"\r\n                \"));\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button @__ctrl1;\r\n            \r\n            #line 25 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl1 = this.@__BuildControlbtnSubmit();\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            \r\n            #line 25 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__parser.AddParsedSubObject(@__ctrl1);\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            \r\n            #line 25 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__parser.AddParsedSubObject(new System.Web.UI.LiteralControl(\"\r\n                 \r\n                \"));\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            return @__ctrl;\r\n        }\r\n        \r\n        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]\r\n        private void @__BuildControl__control7(System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCellCollection @__ctrl) {\r\n            global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell @__ctrl1;\r\n            \r\n            #line 17 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl1 = this.@__BuildControl__control8();\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            \r\n            #line 17 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl.Add(@__ctrl1);\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell @__ctrl2;\r\n            \r\n            #line 17 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl2 = this.@__BuildControl__control9();\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            \r\n            #line 17 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl.Add(@__ctrl2);\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell @__ctrl3;\r\n            \r\n            #line 17 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl3 = this.@__BuildControl__control10();\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            \r\n            #line 17 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl.Add(@__ctrl3);\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n        }\r\n        \r\n        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]\r\n        private global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow @__BuildControl__control6() {\r\n            global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow @__ctrl;\r\n            \r\n            #line 17 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl = new global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow();\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            \r\n            #line 17 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl.Align = \"center\";\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            \r\n            #line 17 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            this.@__BuildControl__control7(@__ctrl.Cells);\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            return @__ctrl;\r\n        }\r\n        \r\n        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]\r\n        private global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal @__BuildControllTextData() {\r\n            global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal @__ctrl;\r\n            \r\n            #line 34 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl = new global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal();\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            this.lTextData = @__ctrl;\r\n            \r\n            #line 34 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl.ID = \"lTextData\";\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            return @__ctrl;\r\n        }\r\n        \r\n        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]\r\n        private global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel @__BuildControlpnlDisplayData() {\r\n            global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel @__ctrl;\r\n            \r\n            #line 31 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl = new global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel();\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            this.pnlDisplayData = @__ctrl;\r\n            @__ctrl.ApplyStyleSheetSkin(this);\r\n            \r\n            #line 31 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl.ID = \"pnlDisplayData\";\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            \r\n            #line 31 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl.Visible = false;\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            System.Web.UI.IParserAccessor @__parser = ((System.Web.UI.IParserAccessor)(@__ctrl));\r\n            \r\n            #line 31 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__parser.AddParsedSubObject(new System.Web.UI.LiteralControl(\"\r\n        \r\n            \r\n       \" +\r\n                        \"         \"));\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal @__ctrl1;\r\n            \r\n            #line 31 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__ctrl1 = this.@__BuildControllTextData();\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            \r\n            #line 31 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__parser.AddParsedSubObject(@__ctrl1);\r\n            \r\n            #line default\r\n            #line hidden\r\n            \r\n            #line 31 \"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\DataMatch.aspx\"\r\n            @__parser.AddParsedSubObject(new System.Web.UI.LiteralCont

Comment: As a simple solution, have you tried `Response.Redirect` instead?

Comment: No, but I will try this and post back the results.  Thanks.

Comment: Response.Redirect didn't work for me because it asks for a URL instead and the URL strings I tried didn't work.  This is my default website application.  What is wrong with:
Response.Redirect("http://localhost/WpfApp1/DataMatch.aspx");

It says that "/WpfApp1/DataMatch.aspx" is not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest trying `Response.Redirect("New page URL")` since you have been having trouble with Server.transfer.  Response.Redirect seems like a "cleaner" way to change pages.  See http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3299641/ServerTransfer-Vs-ResponseRedirect.htm for a comparison.

Comment: Quote : Please avoid using Server.Transfer, using it is rarely a sign of good design... – Matti Virkkunen from salvationishere's previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647731/how-to-create-a-server-control-on-another-aspx-file

Comment: IMO Server.Transfer usually causes me more trouble than it is worth, and it's consequential error messages are always quite baffling.

Comment: Awesome I got this working now with Response.Redirect!  Thanks for the helps and advice!